# how to append tuple to excel by Openpyxl? (already change Tuple to List)

Tags: python, openpyxl

I extracted data from Excel by Pandas, and then gave out a tuple result. So I changed the tuple result to list, and appended it to another Excel worksheet by openpyxl. However, it brings an error: `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'`

[image: data source]

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:/work/111.xlsx', '222', skiprows = 0, nrows=30,  usecols= 'A:C')
```

[image: Data is extracted by Pandas, and give out tuple result]

Then, I turn the tuple into list in the following code

```
df_list = df.values
de_list = list(df_list)
df_list = np.array(df_list)
df_list = df_list.tolist()

print(df_list)

type_df_list=type(df_list)
print(type_df_list)
```

[image: the tuple has already turn to list]

Then, I append the list and get the error `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'`

```
op_wb = op.load_workbook(r'C:/work/111.xlsx').active
op_sht_333 = op_wb['333']

for i in df_list:
   op_sht_333.append(i)

op_wb.save('111.xlsx')
```

This is my code:

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:/work/111.xlsx', '222', skiprows = 0, nrows=30,  usecols= 'A:C')

df_list = df.values
de_list = list(df_list)
df_list = np.array(df_list)
df_list = df_list.tolist()

print(df_list)

type_df_list=type(df_list)
print(type_df_list)

op_wb = op.load_workbook(r'C:/work/111.xlsx').active
op_sht_333 = op_wb['333']

for i in df_list:
   op_sht_333.append(i)

op_wb.save('111.xlsx')
```

Is there anyway to turn the data enable to append?

Comment: See https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pandas.html

Comment: thanks, but i tried to use dataframe_to_rows, and still give out the same error:   'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: Then your code is incomplete or inaccurate. Provide the full traceback and doube-check.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
op_wb = op.load_workbook(r'111.xlsx').active
```

relates to a worksheet, so `op_wb` is the active **worksheet** in the workbook `111.xlsx`.

This means the next line

```
op_sht_333 = op_wb['333']
```

makes `op_sht_333` a **tuple** not a **worksheet** and therefore using `op_sht_333.append` will give the error;

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Using `op_wb` instead

```
op_wb.append(i)
```

will work because `op_wb` is a worksheet object.

Answer (score 0):

the problem finally is solved by using **openpyxl.utils.dataframe**, but the code is a little different from: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pandas.html

if using below, it will still have the same error: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'  :

```
wb = Workbook() 
ws = wb.active
```

But if remove the **.active** from ws = wb.active, the code is working and pasted selected dataframe. the working code example is :

```
import openpyxl as op
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb   #remove .active

for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=True, header=True):
    ws.append(r)

for cell in ws['A'] + ws[1]:
    cell.style = 'Pandas'

wb.save("pandas_openpyxl.xlsx")
```

to instill **openpyxl.utils.dataframe**:

```
pip install openpyxl-utilities
```